# Error: Returned error: Transaction nonce is too low. Try incrementing the nonce

Tags: raw-transaction, sendrawtransaction

I receive an error when sending raw transactions. I get the following error message.

```
        Error: Returned error: Transaction nonce is too low. Try incrementing the nonce.
```

I get my nonce this way:

```
    const nonce = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account);
```

I have double-checked and can guarantee that it returns the correct nonce.

Another thing I tried is to increment the nonce like the error message says but I still get the error.

Anyone has an idea why this is the case?

**additional details**
network: Kovan

ethereum client: parity

error occurs after

```
web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(rawTx)
```

Comment: Have you tried incrementing the nonce by one. `const nonce = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account) + 1;`

Comment: Yes, I did. It still tells me the nonce is too low.

Comment: Are you running a program which is sending multiple transactions in a row? You will need to track the nonce on your side in these situations, since the network will be slow to update the latest transaction count until a new block is created.

Comment: okay, I found the problem.... I was signing with the wrong key lol

Comment: if you decode your raw transaction , and compare to the nonce in the node that is in sync with Kovan network, do the nonces differ by +1 ? I mean, decode it by another process, not your code that is sending it.